# How do I get all the HTML selection tags in selected text using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have a minimal Rich text editor created using Javascript and Swift(for use in iOS), that supports simple text formatting like bold, italics and underline using the execCommand command(the formatting actions like bold are outside of the web view in a SwiftUI view). How can I get ALL the tags that encloses the selected text by executing a javascript query? Is there any simple way to do this?

For example, this is slack and when I select the text in the first image it highlights the bold, but when I place the cursor on the "u" in jumps, bold and italics are highlighted.

[image: bold highlight]

[image: bold and italics highlight]

Comment: Maybe is this helpfull? https://zellwk.com/blog/css-values-in-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this solution, based on [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

(press **Run Code Snippet** below to see how it works)

```js
const text = document.querySelector('#text');
const textElements = document.querySelectorAll('#text *');

document.addEventListener('selectionchange', (e) => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  
  if (selection && selection.anchorNode && selection.focusNode) {
    const selectionStartsAtElement = selection.anchorNode.parentNode;
    const selectionEndsAtElement = selection.focusNode.parentNode;
  
    if (selectionStartsAtElement === text && selectionEndsAtElement === text) {
      console.log('no markup elements have been selected');
      return;
    }
  
    const areElementsSelectedInsideText = text.contains(selectionStartsAtElement) && text.contains(selectionEndsAtElement);
    
    if (areElementsSelectedInsideText) {
      console.log('markup elements have been selected');
      
      let parentElementsForSelectionEnd;
      let parentElementsForSelectionStart;
      
      // get selection end elements
      if (selectionEndsAtElement !== text) {
        parentElementsForSelectionEnd = [selectionEndsAtElement];
        
        let nextParentAtSelectionEnd = selectionEndsAtElement.parentNode;

        while (nextParentAtSelectionEnd !== text) {
          parentElementsForSelectionEnd.push(nextParentAtSelectionEnd);
          nextParentAtSelectionEnd = nextParentAtSelectionEnd.parentNode;
        }
      }
      
      // get selection start elements
      if (selectionStartsAtElement !== text) {
        parentElementsForSelectionStart = [selectionStartsAtElement];
        
        let nextParentAtSelectionStart = selectionStartsAtElement.parentNode;

        while (nextParentAtSelectionStart !== text) {
          parentElementsForSelectionStart.push(nextParentAtSelectionStart);
          nextParentAtSelectionStart = nextParentAtSelectionStart.parentNode;
        }
      }

      // do what ever you need here 
      // (as I understood - you should highlight buttons somewhere)
      console.log(parentElementsForSelectionStart);
      console.log(parentElementsForSelectionEnd);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='text'>Test with <i>tags <b>and formatting</b></i></div>
```

***Note!*** This code **is not** final and **is not** production ready.

I'm sure that there are a lot of edge cases and additional requirements to it + it should be refactored (I have created such an example just to make it clear)

Comment: This seems to work pretty well, except that it cannot seem to hold more than one element in the array unless the second element is nested in the first. If you change the example text so that one word is <strong> and another word is <em> but they are not nested, for example, the code does not remember both of them if you select both of them, only the last one. I have been trying to figure out how to alter it so that it would remember all the elements once a selection has been made, but cannot figure it out myself.